# Autotools support for CDT (3.2.0.201309180223) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.ui (3.4.0)", or later version

Tags: eclipse

When I am installing CDT in Eclipse, in the updates I am getting:
"Autotools support for CDT (3.2.0.201309180223) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.ui (3.4.0)", or later version."
error message and If I uncheck and install CDT, it won't work.

I have install mingw for the compiler and working file

Sys Conf: Win 7 64-bit / 4Gb Ram 
Eclipse: Eclipse 3.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indicates that you're trying to install the CDT version for Eclipse 3.4.

Either upgrade your Eclipse IDE or locate an older CDT version.  I would recommend upgrading your Eclipse IDE, as Eclipse 3.3 was [released in 2007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases)! I doubt you can even find a version of CDT that supports that release.